# OAuth 2.0 Client IDs enable access only a groups of users in my internal organisation

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, reverse-proxy

I created a reverse proxy with Apache on CentOS 7.
I configured access to this site using OAuth 2.0 Client IDs on GSuite.

Now works good, and all users in my internal organization can be access on my site.

Now, my question is:
Is it possible to restrict access only to a group?
If an user is member of this group is allowed to access otherwise can't access.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible because google API OAuth2.0 don't manage groups.